# How to flag for close a question that has gone well out of scope for the site

Tags: discussion, support

I'm unsure how to deal with [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48011078/1835379) I had previously attempted to fix. Their own answer was just a code dump originally; I then moved an explanation for the answer from the question to their answer. However, looking again, even with my alterations the question is just ridiculously manipulated past the point of being downright confusing. It has an answer to the question within the question and an alternative answer is also present.

Both of these answers are horrific. The first is just stolen from everyone who answered the question and the second, no programmer looking for help should ever see or use as it has number comparison using strings.

So how should a question like that be marked for closure as none of the options seem to suit the problems with this question?

Comment: That Q. is almost demanding to be closed for... something.

Comment: Probably should be closed just because it's PHP and so just tried to do stuff instead of blowing up with an error:)

Comment: You can use the custom (Other) close reason and explain why you think it is off topic.

Comment: @Nkosi i don't have that option for close, i have duplicate, off-top, unclear, too broad & opinion-based.

Comment: @Nkosi Close > Off Topic > Other :)

Comment: I removed the meta information about the solutions. If anything they should be moved to the answer, but it all looks largely irrelevant (more "this is how I changed my code after this question, yay!" than an "alternative solution") so I just left it out. If the asker wants to move the information to their answer they can. After that, it's still an on-topic programming question. No better or worse than most of the questions we get.

Comment: @TinyGiant it looks loads better now. The how I changed my code thing 
 I'm not sure on as OP said it was an alternative answer but it will produce the same problem using a string comparison for number comparison that's what left with 'i don't know what to do with this'. as he had an answer that might have worked for his limited test but would result in the same problem later on.

Comment: I'd call it unclear, but you can do the personalized close reason if you want.